# WCF Service issue using MVP Design pattern

Tags: c#, wcf, mvp

I've been learning alot about the MVP design pattern as of late.  I have gone through the entire solution up to the point where I'm starting to consume the WCF service on the presentation layer.  Please find the details below for the issue I am running into.

I am using the service reference in the Windows Form Model project.  The Windows Forms Application project references the Model, View, Presenter projects.

The exception i'm running into is:

```
    Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ActionService.IActionService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

The exception occurs in the public constructor of my Presenter class that looks like:

```
public class Presenter<T> where T : IView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the model statically.
    /// </summary>
    protected static IModel Model { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Static constructor
    /// </summary>
    static Presenter()
    {
        Model = new Model();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor. Sets the view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="view">The view.</param>
    public Presenter(T view)
    {
        View = view;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the view.
    /// </summary>
    public T View { get; private set; }
}
```

Here is the code for my concrete presenter class (AppConfigPresenter):

```
public class AppConfigPresenter : Presenter<IApplicationConfigurationView>
{
    public AppConfigPresenter(IApplicationConfigurationView view)
        : base(view)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the application configurations on the form
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="applicationId"></param>
    /// <param name="machineName"></param>
    public void Display(byte applicationId, string machineName)
    {
        View.ApplicationConfigurations = Model.GetApplicationConfigurations(applicationId, machineName);
    }
}
```

In the windows forms application, here is the calling code:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form, IApplicationConfigurationView
{
    private AppConfigPresenter _appConfigPresenter;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _appConfigPresenter = new AppConfigPresenter(this);
    }

    public IList<ApplicationConfigurationModel> ApplicationConfigurations
    {
        set 
        { 
            var applicationConfigurations = value;

            BindApplicationConfigurations(applicationConfigurations);
        }
    }

    private void BindApplicationConfigurations(IList<ApplicationConfigurationModel> applicationConfigurations)
    {
        foreach(var config in applicationConfigurations)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(config.ConfigKey);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       _appConfigPresenter.Display(7, "xxxxxxx");
    }
}
```

Here's my web.config located in my hosting layer (which is the layer where the .svc resides.)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="AppConfigBehavior" name="FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceImplementation.AppConfigService">
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceContracts.IActionService">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
      </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="AppConfigBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is my app.config that is in my Windows Forms Model Project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51516/ActionService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IActionService"
                contract="ActionService.IActionService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

EDIT:

Here's is my service contact:

```
namespace FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceContracts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// IService is the interface for Patterns in Action public services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Application Facade Pattern.
    /// </remarks>
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
    public interface IActionService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        TokenResponse GetToken(TokenRequest request);

        [OperationContract]
        ApplicationConfigurationResponse GetApplicationConfigurations(ApplicationConfigurationRequest request);
    }
}
```

Here is my .svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceImplementation.AppConfigService" %>
```

My new App.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51516/ActionService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IActionService"
                contract="FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceImplementation.AppConfigService" name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am still getting the same error as previously mentioned.

NEW EDIT:

Whenever I update the service reference, it's adding more to the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51516/ActionService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IActionService"
                contract="FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceImplementation.AppConfigService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:51516/ActionService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IActionService1"
                contract="ActionService.IActionService" name="WSHttpBinding_IActionService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract names must be identical (including namespace) in the configs and service contract.  It looks you've got a mismatch: *FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceContracts.IActionService *vs.* 'ActionService.IActionService'*

Comment: I added in some edits, but I am still getting the same error as before.  What else can I give to you guys for some ideas?

Comment: Does the endpoint name in the App.config need to be same as the contract name?

Comment: No, but I think it has to be the same as the name in the .svc

Comment: Ok I've modified the App.config, take a look at it.  It matches what's in the .svc right above the New App.config.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: Change the name in the new config to FileManipulationServiceLayer.ServiceImplementation.AppConfigService

Comment: After trying both, it still doesn't work.  In the solution example that I have, it is congruent with my original app.config using the namespace to my IActionService according to the service reference.  I've gone back and tried that again, which puts me back at square 1.

Comment: Delete your service reference and add a new one.  This will cleanup your config file.  If your hosting the service on IIS, get to the svc file and browse it to make sure it works (right click).

Comment: Ok I've done that, and the exception message is now saying: "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."  And the inner exception for the FaultException says: "The message could not be processed because the action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence' is invalid or unrecognized."   Btw, going to the address for the service is working correctly.  As far as not giving any errors haha.

Comment: Is that coming from the service when you browsed the svc?

Comment: Nope it's coming from the Exception caught at the public constructor of the Presenter base class.

Comment: I'll be leaving soon, so let's try a couple of things.  First, you have to verify that your service is running.  That will give you confirmation that the service is good.  Create a simple UI project and add a service reference.  If it works, copy its config file's <ServiceModel> section into your MVP solution.  Any other errors you get will be unrelated to your service stack.

Comment: Ok so what I did was create a new UI project like you suggested and added the service reference.  It boiled down to a few null exceptions in my DataAccess layer.  Fixing those and changing <reliableSession enabled="false"/> seemed to fix the original exception in my original project UI.                                                                                               Thanks again for the help!